# Prove that, for every intermediate value, there exists a sequence that converges to it.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, limsup-and-liminf

I want to prove that:

> If the continuous function $f(x)$ has a bounded limit as $x$ goes to $\infty$ i.e $$0<L=\liminf (f)\leq S=\limsup(f)<\infty,$$ then for every $x_0 \in [L,S]$ there exists a sequence $x_n$ and $x_n$ goes to $\infty$ as $n$ goes to  $\infty$ such that $$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n)=x_0.$$

Comment: Is $x_{0}$ a member of the sequence as well? Or is the first member of the sequence some $x_{1} \neq x_{0}$?

Comment: It's clear if $L=S$. If $L<S$, then for any $a\in(L,S)$ you can find $x_n\to \infty$ so that $f(x_n)=a$ by continuity of $f$.

Comment: graydad 
there is no relation between $x_0$ and the sequence members

Comment: Quang Hoang 
what is the relation between the continuity and this sequence, since this sequence goes to $\infty$

Answer (score 0):

If $x_0\in\{L,R\}$, the result is trivial.
Otherwise, there is $\varepsilon>0$ such that $x_0\in[L+\varepsilon,R-\varepsilon]$. For any $n>0$ there exist $a,b>n$ such that $f(a)<L+\varepsilon$, $f(b)<R-\varepsilon$. Use [Intermediate value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) to show that, for some $c>n$, one has $f(c)=x_0$.

Comment: thank you, for your help, I understand the solution.